# How do I write a recurring decimal in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

Title says it all. Since I am a newbie, I don't know how to do this.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to write? Because it is unclear what you mean by "recurring decimal"

Comment: @tohecz like `0.9` with a dot on top of the 9.

Comment: Is this what you want: `0.\dot{9}`?

Comment: and how do you write `17/99` then? This way? `0.\dot{1}\dot{7}`. We used to write `0.\overline{17}`, recently I use `0.(17)^\omega` and my friends `0.(17)^{\mathbb{N}}`. This just shows that there're many ways how to write it and you _have to_ specify which exactly you want to typeset.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451455/128553.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you're thinking of using a horizontal bar over a recurring group of decimals, you could use the `\overline` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{1}{7}=0.\overline{142857}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For people using this with `siunitx`, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97329/90237

Answer (score 39):

There are at least four representations; here is a way to produce all of them, take your pick (the macro names can of course be modified). I strongly suggest to use a special macro name, even if you decide to use the overline, so you can change your mind later and choose another realization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Dots on the first and last digit
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodfl}{m}
 {
  \repdec_initial_final_dots:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__repdec_digits_seq
\tl_new:N \l__repdec_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__repdec_last_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \repdec_initial_final_dots:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__repdec_digits_seq {} { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__repdec_digits_seq \l__repdec_first_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__repdec_digits_seq \l__repdec_last_tl
  \quark_if_no_value:VF \l__repdec_first_tl { \dot{\l__repdec_first_tl} }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__repdec_digits_seq {}{}{}
  \quark_if_no_value:VF \l__repdec_last_tl { \dot{\l__repdec_last_tl} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \quark_if_no_value:nF { V }

%% Dots on all digits
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodalldots}{m}
 {
  \repdec_initial_all_dots:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \repdec_initial_all_dots:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \dot{##1} }
 }

%% Bar over period
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodbar}{m}
 {
  \overline{ #1 }
 }

%% Parentheses around period
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodparens}{m}
 {
  (#1)
 }

%% Dot on unique digit, bar on several digits
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodmixed}{m}
 {
  \repdec_mixed:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \repdec_mixed:n #1
 {
  \int_case:nnn { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    { 0 } { }
    { 1 } { \dot{#1} }
   }
   {
    \overline{#1}
   } 
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$1.2\periodfl{3}$ --- $1.2\periodfl{34}$ --- $1.2\periodfl{345}$ --- 
$1.2\periodfl{3456}$ --- $1.2\periodfl{34567}$

\medskip
$1.2\periodalldots{3}$ --- $1.2\periodalldots{34}$ --- $1.2\periodalldots{345}$ --- 
$1.2\periodalldots{3456}$ --- $1.2\periodalldots{34567}$

\medskip
$1.2\periodbar{3}$ --- $1.2\periodbar{34}$ --- $1.2\periodbar{345}$ --- 
$1.2\periodbar{3456}$ --- $1.2\periodbar{34567}$

\medskip
$1.2\periodparens{3}$ --- $1.2\periodparens{34}$ --- $1.2\periodparens{345}$ --- 
$1.2\periodparens{3456}$ --- $1.2\periodparens{34567}$


\medskip
$1.2\periodmixed{3}$ --- $1.2\periodmixed{34}$ --- $1.2\periodmixed{345}$ ---
$1.2\periodmixed{3456}$ --- $1.2\periodmixed{34567}$

\end{document}
```

For `\periodbar` and `\periodparens` the overhead of `xparse` is not necessary and they can be realized with the standard

```
\newcommand{\periodbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\periodparens}[1]{(#1)}
```

[image]

---

A different definition of `\repdec_initial_final_dots:n` can be as follows

```
\int_new:N \l__repdec_digits_int
\int_new:N \l__repdec_count_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \repdec_initial_final_dots:n #1
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__repdec_digits_int { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
  \int_zero:N \l__repdec_count_int
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \__repdec_add_dot:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__repdec_add_dot:n #1
 {
  \int_incr:N \l__repdec_count_int
  \int_case:nnn { \l__repdec_count_int }
   {
    { 1 } { \dot{#1} }
    { \l__repdec_digits_int } { \dot{#1} }
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }
```

However, the sequence method seems more general.

---

Just for completeness, here is a possible approach for this macro in the traditional LaTeX programming:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\periodfl}[1]{\@periodflold#1\@nil\relax}
\def\@periodflold#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\@periodflold@i#1#2}%
}
\def\@periodflold@i#1#2{%
  \dot{#1}%
  \ifx#2\@nil
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\@periodflold@ii#2}%
}
\def\@periodflold@ii#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\@nil
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\dot{#1}}{#1\@periodflold@ii#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: OMG the first two look so confusing!

Comment: @tohecz According to the Wikipedia page they are used. I don't find the first particularly confusing.

Comment: @tohecz I'm used to the first one :-)

Comment: I would use the dot (first or second option) for a single digit, and either the bar or multiple dots (second or third option) for multiple digits. So the second option would work for me, but I'd prefer to use the bar for multiple digits and the dot for a single digit.

Comment: @TRiG I don't find that mixing dots and bars is sound, but I've added `\periodmixed`.

Comment: @egreg. Quick work! I'm impressed.

Comment: There is even another one, which is quite easy, but it takes more space: `1.233... -- 1.23434... -- 1.2345345... -- 1.234563456... -- etc.`

Comment: @Egon How would you write 1.23453(45)? As "1.234534545..."?

Comment: @Random832: indeed, "1.234534545..." (so it's always: fixed part, repeating part twice and ellipsis)

Comment: @Random832: I would advise against using parenthesis, as they are used for uncertainty.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty#Measurements

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Where repeating decimals are used it's quite improbable to need also uncertainty measurements. Mathematics is full of contradictory notations, also in one and the same book, sometimes. One should always pay attention to notation, and so your comment is certainly to be taken into consideration.