# siunitx does not work with overline

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

When I am typing a laboratory for physics, I tried using `\overline` inside `SI` from the `siunitx` package, like so:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
s &= \frac{d}{t}\\
&= \frac{\SI{1.15}{m}}{\SI{1.43}{s}}\\
&= \SI{0.\overline{804195}}{m/s}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

But it seems that it does not work when you have `\overline` inside `SI`, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also set the number parsing off temporarily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
s &= \frac{d}{t}\\
&= \frac{\SI{1.15}{m}}{\SI{1.43}{s}}\\
&= \SI[parse-numbers=false]{0.\overline{804195}}{m/s}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a more "canonical" usage of `\SI`, you may want to write `\frac{\SI{1.15}{\meter}}{\SI{1.43}{\second}}` and `\SI[parse-numbers=false,per-mode=symbol]{0.\overline{804195}}{\meter\per\second}`. I.e., let `siunitx` do the mapping from `\meter` and `\second` to the letters `m` and `s`.

Comment: @Mico True but note that the `literal` mode of `siunitx` is also canonical as opposed to `interpreted` mode. The units here don't matter much as overline is the emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

This does sort-of defeat the purpose of using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), but it's possible with some box manipulation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{siunitx,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    s &= \frac{d}{t} \\
     &= \frac{\SI{1.15}{m}}{\SI{1.43}{s}} \\
     &= \rlap{$\phantom{0.}\overline{\phantom{804\,195}}$}\SI{0.804195}{m/s}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I've pre-set an invisible `0.804\,195` with a visible `\overline` (only over the necessary part) using a `r`ight over`lap` (a zero-width, left-aligned box). After this, `\SI` sets things as usual, this time "underneath" the `\overline` so it looks appropriate.